# How to Search and Display Data From MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can i be able to search and retrieve data from a mysql table fields. When the records are found then the user is notified the record was found.
I have created my html form with action and php script to fetch data from the database.

When i click on search it only displays no records found.

I want to fetch data from 3 fields in the table.

my  html form below

````
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Conduct Database Search</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body,
    td,
    th {
      font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p><img src="images/logonew.png" width="150" height="73" alt="Find Real Me Logo" /> </p>
  <hr>
  <p>Welcome to the conduct database search page. You can verify domestic worker's conduct and history.
  </p>
  <p>Search database by entering First name, Middle name and ID No. below and click the Search Conduct Database.
  </p>
  <form id="form1" action="search15.php" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="First_name">First name:</label>
      <input name="First_name" type="text" required="required" id="First_name" title="First name" size="30" maxlength="30">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="Last_name">Last name:</label>
      <input name="Last_name" type="text" required="required" id="Last_name" title="last_name" size="30" maxlength="30">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ID_NO">ID Number:</label>
      <input name="ID_NO" type="number" required="required" id="ID_NO" title="ID_NO">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" formaction="search15.php" formmethod="POST" value="Search Conduct  Database">
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <p>Copyright All Rights Reserved </p>
</body>

</html>

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
  <title>Conduct Database Search Results</title>
  <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
  <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- body {
      font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-color: #006600;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      color: #000;
    }
    /* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */

    ul,
    ol,
    dl {
      /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding and margin 
    on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here, or on the list items 
    (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will cascade to the .nav list unless you 
    write a more specific selector. */
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    p {
      margin-top: 0;
      /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their 
    containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the divs, instead of 
    the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with side padding can also be 
    used as an alternate method. */
    }

    a img {
      /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers around an image 
    when it is surrounded by a link */
      border: none;
    }
    /* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors 
    that 
    create the hover effect. ~~ */

    a:link {
      color: #42413C;
      text-decoration: underline;
      /* unless you style your links to look extremely unique, it's best to 
    provide underlines for quick visual identification */
    }

    a:visited {
      color: #6E6C64;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a:hover,
    a:active,
    a:focus {
      /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same 
    hover 
    experience as the person using a mouse. */
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    /* ~~ this fixed width container surrounds the other divs ~~ */

    .container {
      width: 960px;
      background-color: #FFF;
      margin: 0 auto;
      /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
    }
    /* ~~ the header is not given a width. It will extend the full width of your layout. It contains an 
    image placeholder that should be replaced with your own linked logo ~~ */

    .header {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    /* ~~ This is the layout information. ~~ 

    1) Padding is only placed on the top and/or bottom of the div. The elements within this div have 
    padding on their sides. This saves you from any "box model math". Keep in mind, if you add any side 
    padding or border to the div itself, it will be added to the width you define to create the *total* 
    width. You may also choose to remove the padding on the element in the div and place a second div 
    within it with no width and the padding necessary for your design.

    */

    .content {
      padding: 10px 0;
    }
    /* ~~ The footer ~~ */

    .footer {
      padding: 10px 0;
      background-color: #333333;
      color: #CCC;
    }
    /* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */

    .fltrt {
      /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must 
    precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
      float: right;
      margin-left: 8px;
    }

    .fltlft {
      /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must 
    precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
      float: left;
      margin-right: 8px;
    }

    .clearfloat {
      /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following 
    the last floated div (within the #container) if the #footer is removed or taken out of the 
     #container */
      clear: both;
      height: 0;
      font-size: 1px;
      line-height: 0px;
    }

    -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div align="left">
        <a href="#"> </a>
        <img src="logo.png" width="180" height="88"></div>

      <!-- end .header -->
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div align="right"></div>
      <div align="right">
        <p><a href="http://localhost/frm_test2">Home</a> | <a href="http://localhost/frm_test2/services">Services </a> | <a href="http://localhost/frm_test2/contact">Contact</a> | <a href="http://localhost/frm_test/conduct_check.html">Search Again</a></p>
        <hr>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <h1>Results</h1>
      <?php 
     //load database connection
     $host = "localhost";
     $user = "mydata";
     $password = "mydata";
     $database_name = "mydata";
     $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
     ));
    // Search from MySQL database table
    $search=$_POST['submit'];
    $query = $pdo->prepare("select * from red_data1 where ID_NO LIKE '%$search%' OR First_name LIKE 
    '%$search%' OR Middle_name LIKE '%$search%' OR Last_name LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 0 , 10");
    $query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    // Display search result
         if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
                echo "Your Reference Search <b>found</b> the following in our database:<br/> <br/>";
                echo "<a href='http://localhost/frm_test2/contact' target='_blank'>Click here </a> to 
    contact us for more information relating to your search.<br/> <br/>";
                echo "<table style=\"font-family:arial;color:#333333;\">";  
                echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border- 
    color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">ID No.</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border- 
    width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">First Name</td><td style=\"border- 
    style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Middle Name</td><td 
    style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Last 
    Name</td> 
    </tr>";             
            while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
                echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";            
                echo $results['ID_NO'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
                echo $results['First_name'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
                echo $results['Middle_name'];
                echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
                echo $results['Last_name'];
                echo "</td></tr>";              
            }
                echo "</table>";        
        } else {
            echo 'No Records found ';
        }
     ?>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <!-- end .content -->
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p align="center">Copyright </p>
      <!-- end .footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .container -->
  </div>



</body>

</html>
````

Comment: You use `bindvalue()` method but there is no place holder inside you SQL query

Comment: also please only include relevant code inside your question, there is no need for us to know your CSS code in this question, it only makes your question harder to read.

Comment: `$search=$_POST['submit'];` -> submit is the name of the submit button, your search term will always be `Search Conduct  Database`

Comment: Thanks for the response and apologies for css code i am a newbe in this. Please help me on the bindValue() method and how it should execute.

Answer (score 0):

$search = $_POST['search'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONCAT('database column names') LIKE '%".$search."%' ";

Comment: Thanks for the response i have made the changes and getting results output working okay. in one column ID_NO i have got null values how do i make the column unique at the moment it displays every section with null.

Comment: Add one column in database table at top of all the columns and make that column as a auto increment which is retrun as in datbase like A.I. and also add that column in your while loop to get the result on screen.